# what is the difference between ${jboss_home} and ${env.jboss_home}

Tags: java, ant, jboss

Could you please let me know the difference between giving ${jboss_home} and ${env.jboss_home}.

I just want to understand whether the ${env.jboss_home} will fetch the value from enviornment variables?

Comment: `jboss_home` is your variable, `<property environment="env"/>`provides all environment variables as Ant properties prefixed by "env."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${jboss_home}` reads property which you might have specified either using:

- property file like `<property file="build.properties"/>`
- or something individually defiend property like `<property name="jboss_home" value="test"/><!--can be location as well instead of value-->`

When you say `${env.jboss_home}`, it means you might be getting values from one of the environment variable that you might have defined. You should have defined env something like:

```
<property environment="env"/>
```

So if you run either `echo $jboss_home` from unix shell or `echo %jboss_home%` from windows, then you would see the value assigned to it and which is what you are trying to use in your ant.